# Getting Child Elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get the child elements in HTML using JavaScript?

Program:

```js
$(function(){
  var child = document.getElementById("row");
  var i;
  $("#subpage").html(child.childNodes.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
    <td> This is td </td>
    <td> This is td2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="subpage"> </div>
```

I expect the above program will print output as "2". But it gives "5". The element which contains id as "row" have 2 elements which is
td. But it gives "5". So how "5" is printed ?

Output:

```
This is td  This is td2
5
```

Comment: use document.getElementById("#row > td").length

Comment: using pure js only then no jquery?

Comment: use `children` property instead of `childNodes` and search for the difference between the two.

Comment: If you are using jQurey you can also use: https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: @guradio The OP is already using jQuery and it is tagged in the question...

Comment: @Semi-Friends: `querySelector`, not `getElementById`.

Comment: title is `in Javascript` @NewToJS

Comment: @guradio Correct but no mention of converting the current source code into pure javascript. Just a question to why the output isn't as expected.

Comment: childNodes includes the line terminators before the child element and before the last closing tag. In your markup there are 3 line terminators and 2 child elements so in total 5

Comment: oyeah sorry i mistyped it `document.querySelectorAll("#row > td").length`

Answer (score 3):

You're getting 5 because there are two [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and three [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) inside that row, `childNodes` is exactly that: child *nodes*. There are multiple kinds of nodes (primarily: elements, text nodes, and comment nodes). Here are the nodes in that structure:

```js
$(function(){
  console.log("nodeType 1 is Element, 3 is Text");
  var child = document.getElementById("row");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < child.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    
    console.log(i + ": nodeType = " + child.childNodes[i].nodeType);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
    <td> This is td </td>
    <td> This is td2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="subpage"> </div>
```

If you want just child *elements*, use the DOM's [`children` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) (available on all modern browsers but not some very old ones):

```js
$(function(){
  console.log("nodeType 1 is Element, 3 is Text");
  var child = document.getElementById("row");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < child.children.length; ++i) {
    
    console.log(i + ": nodeType = " + child.children[i].nodeType);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
    <td> This is td </td>
    <td> This is td2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="subpage"> </div>
```

...or jQuery's [`children` method](http://api.jquery.com/children):

```js
$(function(){
  console.log("nodeType 1 is Element, 3 is Text");
  var child = document.getElementById("row");
  var i;
  $(child).children().each(function(i) {
    console.log(i + ": nodeType = " + this.nodeType);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
    <td> This is td </td>
    <td> This is td2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="subpage"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you inspect what sits inside `child.childNodes`?
According to docs

> Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is
>   considered as nodes. Comments are also considered as nodes.

This is why you are getting 5 instead of 2 as there are 3 additional text nodes which you didn't expect. Use `child.children` instead.

```js
$(function(){
  var row = document.querySelector('#row');
  var row_no_ws = document.querySelector('#row_no_ws');
  var subpage = document.querySelector('#subpage');
  subpage.innerHTML = 'Row childNodes: ' + row.childNodes.length + '<br>' +
      'Row using children: ' + row.children.length + '<br>' +
      'Row childNodes no whitespaces: ' + row_no_ws.childNodes.length
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
    <td> This is td </td>
    <td> This is td2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr id="row_no_ws"><td> This is td </td><td> This is td2 </td></tr>
</table>

<div id="subpage"> </div>
```

Comment: Which docs are you quoting there? Please link/cite them.

Comment: Well it's not the official docs(at least I didn't find any at w3.org), but you can find some information about it here and there: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#introduction-to-the-dom http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace_in_the_DOM

Answer (score 1):

If you do console log `console.log(child.childNodes)`

[image]

It also includes whitespaces before  elements and between .childNodes also count those whitespaces as child. if you use `child.childrens.length` it will ignore whitespaces and give count as 2.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use jQuery `children()`.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#subpage").html($("#row").children().length);
  /* you could also use 
  $("#subpage").html($("#row").children("td").length);
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
    <td> This is td </td>
    <td> This is td2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="subpage"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Reference to w3schools - [HTML DOM childNodes Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp)

> Note: Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is
>   considered as nodes. Comments are also considered as nodes.

there by,

```
<tr id ="row">
   newline
   <td>
   newline
   <td>
   newline
</tr>

So, it has 5 child Nodes.
```

> In your case, if the html construction is `<tr id="row"><td></td><td></td></tr>,`
>   it would be 2

Answer (score 0):

you can just do `$("#row td")` with jQuery to get `td`'s nested within `#row`

```js
$(function(){
  var child = $("#row td");
  $("#subpage").html(child.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="row">
    <td> This is td </td>
    <td> This is td2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="subpage"> </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#subpage").html($('#row td').length);
```

Comment: This is not what OP is looking

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("subpage").children.length;
```

Comment: OP is not looking for this. He is asking **Why the length returned 5**